# Segmentation Fault 11 when assigning struct variable

Tags: c

I am trying to initialize some variables in my struct, but I am getting a seg fault when assigning my front variable to equal zero. Specifically newBuff->front = 0;

```
typedef struct buffer{
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t shout;
    int front;
    int rear;
    char bytes[1024];
} buffer;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (argc != 2){
        printf("You must enter in a file name\n");
    }
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(file));
    int shmid;
    char path[] = "~";
    key_t key = ftok(path, 7);
    shmid = shmget(key, SIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL); //shared memory creation
    buffer* newBuff = (buffer*) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    newBuff->front = 0;
```

Comment: What does `shmat` return? Are you sure that worked?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example?

Comment: @machine_1 Pro tip: Use `[mcve]` to get a fancy link, like this: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not checking the value of `newBuff` returned by `shmat()` to ensure that it is not invalid, e.g. `(void*) -1` (per http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmop.2.html). You also need to check the return value of `shmget()` to ensure that it succeeded in the first place.

Almost certainly, `newBuff` is -1, and trying to dereference that gives you a segfault.

Comment: I checked the return values again and you are correct. Once I deleted the shared memory segment it went through fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

several things I can see:

1. Wrong control of the arguments. You are checking them, but are you exiting your program? ;)
2. You are not checking the result when you invoke functions as shmat. Review the manual (man shmat).

Said the above, I can not see your whole code, but this is my recommendation:

```
typedef struct buffer{
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t shout;
    int front;
    int rear;
    char bytes[1024];
} buffer;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int shmid = -1;
    FILE *file = NULL;
    if (argc != 2){
        printf("You must enter in a file dumbass\n");
        // And you must terminate here your program!
        return 1;
    }
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    // Another check that you are not making and can raise a SIGVSEG
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("The file '%s' can not be opened\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("File size: %lu\n", sizeof(file));
    char path[] = "~";
    key_t key = ftok(path, 7);
    // Another check
    if (key == -1) {
        fclose(f);
        printf("The path '%s' does not exist or cannot be accessed\n", path);
        return 1;
    }
    shmid = shmget(key, SIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
    // One more check
    if (shmid == -1) {
        fclose(f);
        printf("An error happened getting shared memory identifier\n");
        return 1;
    }
    buffer* newBuff = (buffer*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    // And finally! Another potential source that could raise a SIGVSEG
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fclose(f);
        printf("An error happened getting the shared memory area\n");
        return 1;
    }
    newBuff->front = 0;
```

Please! Check every return of the functions! You can not imagine how many real problems happen because such returns are not checked properly because of bad practices.